# How to get values from functions from within an if statement

Tags: rust

I am trying to avoid running a function if the user presents some information.

```
if let Some(app) = app.subcommand_matches("Download") {
    if app.is_present("Server") {
        let best = app.value_of("Server").unwrap();
    } else {
        let best = server::best_server("3").unwrap().to_owned();
        let best = best.id.as_str();
    };
    let bytes = app.value_of("bytes").unwrap_or("100000024");
    let dl = server::download(best, bytes).unwrap();
    println!("Download Results {:#?} mbps", dl);
}
```

I would expect the code to only run `best_server` if `app.is_present` exists.
Why does assigning "best" inside the if statement end in the following error :

```
 --> src/main.rs:80:35
   |  
80 |         let dl = server::download(best.id.as_str(), bytes).unwrap();  
   |                                   ^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Comment: A couple questions: what is supposed to happen inside of the inner `if` statement? (`if app.is_present(...)`) Is it supposed to be returning something or performing an action? It looks like you're trying to assign it to a value or return it from a function, but you're not doing either of those things.

Can you show us your whole code? I'm wondering if your formatting got adjusted and the `let dl = ...` line isn't where we think it is...

Comment: if app.is_present(...) is supposed to either assign a value if app.is_present exists and if it does not exist then run a function and grab some values. I will edit with an update.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. If you don't call `server::best_server`, where is `best` supposed to come from?

Comment: Best comes from the user. When the user provides the server number via a subcommand argument.

Comment: The github is available https://github.com/zpeters/speedtestr

Comment: Section from the Book introducing scope: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#variable-scope

Comment: Also note that `if` is in fact an expression: [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#if-expressions), so it can be used in an assignment.

Comment: Links are great, but they are *not sufficient*. Your **question** must contain the complete code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `let` keyword you are declaring the given variable within the scope that the statement appears. The scope starts from the enclosing opening brace `{` and ends at the enclosing closing brace `}`.

So this:

```
if app.is_present("Server") {
    let best = app.value_of("Server").unwrap();
}
```

declares a variable `best`, but that variable does not exist after the closing brace. That's why the error you are getting says the variable does not exist.

One way to fix this is to take advantage of the fact that an `if` statement has a value: the value of the last expression within the selected branch. So you could say:

```
let best = if app.is_present("Server") {
    app.value_of("Server").unwrap()
} else {
    server::best_server("3").unwrap().to_owned().id.as_str()
};
```

Note the lack of a `;` on the end of the expressions within the if statement branches. If there was a semicolon there then the value of the expression would not be assigned.